# Getting the Program Process (Service and Daemon) on Linux in C

Tags: c, unix

I'd like to know how one would create an application that starts in the background. I'm currently creating a webserver in C as a little project, both to learn some old C and Linux Socket Programming. But my current concern is:

- How do I get the current process number?

I want to get this because when I start the process, I want to display the process number for the user who starts the service.

- My second problem is, how do I start my application as a Daemon to run in the background?

Any references, tutorials and/or videos on how I'd do this is appreciated!

---

Maybe I was a little bit unclear; I want to get the Process ID from within C. So, do I need to create a shell script for my application or can I do this from C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To get the running process' identifier, use the `getpid()` function.
2. To create a daemon, i.e. a detached process running in the background, follow [these instructions](http://www-theorie.physik.unizh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize).

Answer (score 1):

On *nix, get the process id with [ps](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ups.htm)
or if you know the process name, do

```
ps aux | grep processname
```

And to run any program as a daemon, use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Comment: I'd like to get it programmatically. From within the C-program. Or do you suggest that i create a shell-script?

Comment: JesperE's answer is spot-on if you want to do it programmatically.